# angularJS - Save params during navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters, angular-routing

Imagine a classic tabulation system, on a page (ex : /#/page).

**In the controller :**

```
angular.module('app').controller("Ctrl", '$routeParams', function($routeParams) {
this.tab = 1;
}]);
```

**In the view (/#/page) :**

```
<li ng-class="{ 'active': ctrl.tab == 1 }">
<a href ng-click="ctrl.tab = 1">onglet 1</a>
</li>
<li ng-class="{ 'active': ctrl.tab == 2 }">
<a href ng-click="ctrl.tab = 2">onglet 2</a>
</li>
```

Once you clicked on a tab, it displays the corresponding block. Inside, we have text and links that open a modal modifying the URL (ex: /#/page/action).
For it, i use ngRoute and $routeParams.

The little problem is when the URL changes, the value this.tab resets, but, I am always on the same page.

Is there would be a way to keep this value in my controller ?

Thank you,

Comment: Finaly, i use a service that saves my tab. If i change the route, i keep my param.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reloadOnSearch`:

Where you define your routes, add the following

```
{
    "pattern": "/page",
    "templateUrl": "/path/to/my/template.html",
    "reloadOnSearch": false
},
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me. If i change the route #/page to #/page/action, my param reset.